# Need Suggestion for Architecture of Content Management System for Multimedia Data

Tags: architecture, content-management-system, liferay, multimedia

I need to design the "Content Management System for Multimedia Data". I am considering different architectures. According to my requirements, if you can assist me to decide upon architecture, I will be helpful.

---

### Requirements of the system:

- 3 types of users in the system: Creator, Approver & Viewer
- Creator will create the multimedia contents, mainly video but sometimes static images also.
- Approver will approve the multimedia contents.
- Viewer shall be able to view the multimedia data in adobe flash based video player.(this will be different application, named Viewer App).
- Statistics will be submitted by Viewer App such as number of times particular video played.
- Creator shall upload video files in any format, but application should convert it into appropriate format compatible to viewer app.
- User may also able to configure few parameters for each video, which are specific to Viewer App.
- Creator and Approver shall be able to see different reports.
- Different users can have different rights to perform action as well as user can have role based access to different sections.
- This application can have user pool in terms of thousands.

---

### Questions:

- Does such system already exist, which can be readily referred?
- I have heard lot about liferay. Is it the right architecture for this kind of application?
- If liferay is the right architecture, from where I can start with to develop this kind of application?
- I am ready to buy Commercial off-the-shelf component also, if it can help me to rapidly implement the system.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liferay has a good/fine-grained permissioning system (roles and permissions can be applied to data-level i.e. for a particular file uploaded you can give permissions as to which users can view, who can update and who can delete or who can upload) and can also be integrated with Workflow engines like jBPM and kaleo to approve, reject contents added or updated by Users.

Liferay does not have a full-fleged Viewer application as you have mentioned, but it provides the API to upload documents and media. It provides integration with different preview softwares like openOffice (for viewing `.doc`, `.docx` etc formats), imageMagick (for viewing `pdf` inside browser) and Xuggler (for multi-media files).

There is a `Documents & Media portlet` (D&M) in liferay which you can check which has features like `read-count` of a particular documents & media files uploaded, comments on documents & media files etc. This would give a fair idea if you can proceed with liferay to build your application.

You can build a portlet application based on Liferay's D&M portlet or customize the D&M portlet (*caution! customizing liferay's built-in features comes with a lot of overhead in terms of upgrade*).

Comment: We finally used liferay only. The best part about the liferay is the multi layer organization & users hierarchy and webservice interface for the same. In order to give service to different organization as SaS model, this feature was quite useful.